# Temporarily downgrading to Java5 as smoothly as possible

Tags: java, java-7, java-5

For a University assignment, I need to write a program but use Java 5 for this reason:

> Please use Java5: each time you call the System.out.write() method it
>   issues one write system call. Do not use Java6 or Java7 for this
>   exercise! Its implementation is very different.

I already have Java 7 installed. I'm afraid that if I uninstall it, and then install Java 5, there will be frustrating issues coming up that I need to solve. Can I easily install Java 5 beside Java 7? What's the best way to do this without confusing myself or my computer? I only need Java 5 installed very briefly (few days).

Comment: Just put it under some drive and update JAVA_HOME and PATH environment variables, it would work without issue. (at-least for few days, and note any other program which depends on Java7 will not work)

Answer (score 0):

As [Pradeep said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22455269/temporarily-downgrading-to-java5-as-smoothly-as-possible#comment34153492_22455269), You can have multiple versions of `Java` installed in your system. You have to set the `JAVA_HOME` and add the appropriate Java version `bin` directory to the `PATH` variable. Thus, you can switch between various Java versions by changing `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` appropriately to your requirement.